# Variable doesn't work

Tags: javascript

For some strange reason the code below doesn't work.

```
var xxx = localStorage.getItem('position');
var foo = document.querySelectorAll("div[current_position=' + xxx + ']");
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Some facts:

1. The `localStrorage` work correct - `localStorage.getItem('position')` outputs the correct value. No error here.
2. `current_position` is a number (1, 2, 3, ... etc). If I manually set, for example, `'2'`, like below:

   ```
   var foo = document.querySelectorAll("div[current_position='2']");
   ```

   then the code work as it should. But if I change `'2'` to a `' + xxx + '`, it doesn't work.

*Original question was edited. Thanks to Bhojendra Nepal and Jonah Williams.*

Comment: You still have concatenation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself. The second line of the code should be:

```
var foo = document.querySelectorAll("div[current_position='" +xxx+ "']");
```

And all works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate your variable with strings:

```
var xxx = localStorage.getItem('position');
var foo = document.querySelectorAll("div[current_position=" + xxx + "]");
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Moreover, I would suggest you to use `data-*` attribute for valid html5 elements, so use `data-current-position` instead of `current_position`

Comment: Sorry, that was my miss, I forgot about `'` and `+`. For some strange reason it doesn't work. Also, the original question was edited, according to this correction.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `xxx` is a variable pointing to localstorage, and `"xxx"` is just a string.  You need to insert the value into your string,

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[current_position=" + xxx + "]");
```